# TRACE32 CMM script

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I would like to run the t32 cmm script for accessing memory and read/write test. And tried below code.

```
&srcadd=0x50000000
&destadd=0x50700000

REPEAT 100.
//WHILE (&srcadd<&destadd)
(
D.S ND:0x10:&srcadd %LE %Long 0xdeadface
&srcadd=&srcadd+0x4
)
```

This code worked for first time  and not working on second run, seen different behavior that some of the location not written... random failures if I run the script on X86 core.
Can you please provide any insights on this ?
Also can you tell me how we can store the data from the memory to compare whether its written properly. I am validating internal memory  and read/write test. It would be great if we have any sample t32 script for the same.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. Please improve you question. E.g. How do you indicate that the script is not working on the second run? The WHILE statement in your script is commented. What was your intention to keep it in your example? Also &destadd is not used. Please reduce your example to the bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks much for your kind response and sorry for the incomplete information. Actually I would like to write 0xdeadface value to 0x5000_0000 to 0x5070_0000 range, but with this code, firstly I am trying to learn the 'repeat' (and/or 'while') syntax (thats why I commented out 'while' for now) to access 100*4 bytes of data from 0x5000_0000 address. Can I have simple t32 cmm script which can test the memory for 1MiB i.e read/write/verify.

Comment: For just writing 0xdeadface to ND:0x10:0x50000000 to  ND:0x10:0x50000400 your script looks alright. However you can have that simpler with the single command `Data.Set ND:0x10:0x50000000++0xff  %LE %Long 0xdeadface`. For read-back and check use PRACTICE function `Data.Long(<addr>)` in an `IF` statement.
For testing memory you can also use command `Data.Test ND:0x10:0x50000000++0xff`

Comment: If you want to test your memory you could also look into "Data.Test".